# How to implement atomic reference counter that does not overflow?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, integer-overflow, reference-counting

I was thinking about reference counting based on atomic integers that would be safe from overflow. How to do it?

Please let's not focus on whether such overflow is a realistic problem or not. The task itself got my interest even if not practically important.

---

**Example**

Example implementation of reference counting is shown as an example in [Boost.Atomic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_reference_counters). Based on that example we can extract following sample code:

```
struct T
{
    boost::atomic<boost::uintmax_t> counter;
};

void add_reference(T* ptr)
{
    ptr->counter.fetch_add(1, boost::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void release_reference(T* ptr)
{
    if (ptr->counter.fetch_sub(1, boost::memory_order_release) == 1) {
        boost::atomic_thread_fence(boost::memory_order_acquire);
        delete ptr;
    }
}
```

In addition following explanation is given

> Increasing the reference counter can always be done with `memory_order_relaxed`: New references to an object can only be formed from an existing reference, and passing an existing reference from one thread to another must already provide any required synchronization.
>
> It is important to enforce any possible access to the object in one thread (through an existing reference) to *happen before* deleting the object in a different thread. This is achieved by a "release" operation after dropping a reference (any access to the object through this reference must obviously happened before), and an "acquire" operation before deleting the object.
>
> It would be possible to use `memory_order_acq_rel` for the `fetch_sub` operation, but this results in unneeded "acquire" operations when the reference counter does not yet reach zero and may impose a performance penalty.

**EDIT >>>**

It seems that [Boost.Atomic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_reference_counters) documentation might be wrong here. The `acq_rel` might be needed after all.

At least such is the implementation of `boost::shared_ptr` when done using `std::atomic` (there are other implementations as well). See file [`boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_std_atomic.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_std_atomic.hpp).

Also Herb Sutter mentions it in his lecture [C++ and Beyond 2012: Herb Sutter - atomic<> Weapons, 2 of 2](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2) (reference counting part starts at 1:19:51). Also he seems to be discouraging use of fences in this talk.

Thanks to [user 2501](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082723/2501) for pointing that out in comments below.

**<<< END EDIT**

---

**Initial attempts**

Now the problem is that `add_reference` as written could (at some point) overflow. And it would do so silently. Which obviously could lead to problems when calling matched `release_reference` that would prematurely destroy the object. (Provided that `add_reference` would be then called once again to reach `1`.)

I was thinking how to make `add_reference` detect overflow and fail gracefully without risking anything.

Comparing to `0` once we leave `fetch_add` will not do since between the two some other thread could call `add_reference` again (reaching `1`) and then `release_reference` (erroneously destroying the object in effect).

Checking first (with `load`) will not help either. This way some other thread could add its own reference between our calls to `load` and `fetch_add`.

---

**Is this the solution?**

Then I thought that maybe we could start with `load` but only if then we do `compare_exchange`.

So first we do `load` and get a local value. If it is `std::numeric_limits<boost::uintmax_t>::max()` then we fail. `add_reference` cannot add another reference as all possible are already taken.

Otherwise we make another local value which is the previous local reference count plus `1`.

And now we do `compare_exchange` providing as expected value the original local reference count (this ensures that no other thread modified reference count in the mean time) and as the desired value the incremented local reference count.

Since `compare_exchange` can fail we have to do this (including `load`) in a loop. Until it succeeds or max value is detected.

---

**Some questions**

1. Is such solution correct?
2. What memory ordering would be required to make it valid?
3. Which `compare_exchange` should be used? `_weak` or `_strong`?
4. Would it affect `release_reference` function?
5. Is it used in practice?

Comment: `fetch_add` returns previous value of the atomic. Would this not be sufficient to detect the overflow?

Comment: nit - uint's do not overflow, they wrap, which can be detected.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Well, it is enough to detect, yes. But what the? The counter is already in bad state and AFAIK at that point you cannot safely revert it to correct state before failing yourself.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: Wrap around or overflow - AFAIK not important in this particular scenario. How would you solve this based on the wrap around?

Comment: Suppose you were able to detect the overflow before it happened - what would you do next? How do you plan to recover from such a situation?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: There are some approaches. You could throw. Or `abort`. Or whatever. What is important in the question is how to detect that not what to do about it. As overflow/wrap detection on atomic integers might have more use cases than this one.

Comment: You could `abort` just as well if you detect the overflow after the fact, could you not? Either way, you likely cannot continue program execution safely.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Either way you keep dragging of the topic to less interesting aspects while avoiding the merit - overflow/wrap around with atomic integers.

Comment: Herb Sutter mentioned that you need to have acquire-release semantics for the decrement: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2 at around 1 hour and 22 minutes.

Comment: @2501: So far I watched only the part about reference counting at 1 hour 20 minutes and it does say so. However this is compared to release only version. While Boost proposes release + fence. Then again it seems Herb speaks there against using fences. I'm no expert here. I don't know which is correct. But thanks for noticing!

Comment: @AdamBadura relaxed for increment and acq_rel for decrement. And most importantly, if you're unsure, use the default mode(you don't have to explicitly write it), which is `memory_order_seq_cst`. Otherwise you'll just shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @2501 I just checked how `boost::shared_ptr` is implemented (in 1.61) and when using `std::atomic` (there are other implementations as well) it does use `relaxed` for simple increment (there is also "complicated increment" when done from locking `weak_ptr`) and `acq_rel` when doing decrement.

Comment: @2501 I have edited the question to include this information as well. Now I will seek to raise the issue within Boost itself. Thanks! (Interesting side question by the way: why `boost::shared_ptr` doesn't just use `boost::atomic` and instead provides 19 different implementations of the reference counting on various platforms?)

Comment: I have also created ticket for Boost.Atomic to clear this out (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12309).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is correct, maybe it could be improved with one thing. Currently, if the value reaches max in the local CPU, it can be decreased by another CPU but the current CPU would still cache the old value. It would be worth doing dummy `compare_exchange` with the same `expected` and `newValue` to confirm the max is still there and only then throw an exception (or whatever you want).

For the rest:

It doesn't matter whether you use `_weak` or `_strong` as it will run in loop anyway and therefore the next `load` will get quite reliably the latest value.

For the `add_reference` and `release_reference` - who would then check whether it was really added or not? Would it throw an exception. If yes, it would work probably. But generally it's better to allow such a low level things not to fail and rather use uintptr_t for the reference counter so it could never overflow as it's big enough to cover the address space and therefore any number of objects existing at the same time.

No, it's not used in practice for the above reasons.

Comment: But how about required memory ordering flags for those operations?

Comment: Also I don't get the comment on "dummy `compare_exchange`". When should I do that? After `load`? How would that differ from doing another `load`?

Comment: @AdamBadura : `compare_exchange` will make sure that the max value you expected is still there and would impose synchronization with other processors (or global memory bus). If it failed it would mean you could repeat the load-inc-cmpxchg loop. For the ordering release will make more sense but generally both of them will work.

Answer (score 0):

Quick math: say uint is 32 bits, so max uint is 4G (4 billion something). Each reference/pointer is at least 4 bytes (8 if you are on a 64 bit system) so to overflow you need 16Gbytes of memory dedicated to storing references pointing to the same object, which should point to a serious deign flaw.

I would say it's not a problem today, nor in the foreseeable future.

Comment: I explicitly asked to avoid answers like "this is not a realistic problem". This particular use case might not be realistic but still it remains a problem that could be solved. While it is easy to understand referring to commonly known things. And its solution could be useful in other use cases where overflow checking is desired. Especially if you consider that instead of max possible value you might have some smaller arbitrary limit.

Answer (score -1):

This question is moot. Even assuming atomic increment takes 1 CPU cycle (it does not!), on 4GHz CPU it would take half a year to wrap around 64bit integer, providing CPU does nothing else but keep incrementing.

Taking into account realities of an actual program, I find it hard to believe this is a real issue which can pester you.

Comment: I explicitly asked to avoid answers like "this is not a realistic problem". This particular use case might not be realistic but still it remains a problem that could be solved. While it is easy to understand referring to commonly known things. And its solution could be useful in other use cases where overflow checking is desired. Especially if you consider that instead of max possible value you might have some smaller arbitrary limit.

Comment: I did! In the end it is a question on how to reliably detect (and prevent) overflow/wrap around for atomic integers. I asked it with the reference counting “theme” as I came to it when thinking about it. Could I have removed the “theme”? Yes, I could and maybe even should. But is this “theme” so disturbing that the question cannot be answered?